# Error in bash - unary operator expected with exist -e

Tags: linux, bash

I want to test if two variables exist, after i used "read" to create it. If the user enter just one of two variables i want, it display an error.

There is my code :

```
while true;
do
  echo "Saisissez deux variables x et y sous la forme [x y]"
  read x y

  if [ !-e $x ] || [ !-e $y ] <<<<<< problem ligne
  then
    echo "Vous devez renseigner deux nombres x et y"
  elif [ $x = "." ]
  then
    exit 0
  else
    calcul $x $y
  fi
done
```

and there is the error when i just enter an argument :

```
[: !-e: unary operator expected
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: what if you put spaces between the `!` and the `-e` ?

Comment: The `-e` operator checks if a file with that name exists. You need a space after `!` - the shell requires each command and argument to be a separate token (excepting parentheses, redirection and some other unambiguous details of the syntax). Also you should generally double-quote user input, so `"$x"` pro `$x` and `"$y"` pro `$y`.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I tried to detect if an user press ENTER without any value. I tried to use -e to prevent that, but it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change it to:

```
if [ -z "$x" ] || [ -z "$y" ]
```

**Explanation**

- `[` is actually a shell built-in (try `which [` or `help [` on your prompt); it's is a synonym for `test`.
- `-z` is an argument to `[`. it means "test if the length of the next string is 0; return true if so; return false otherwise.
- Always wrap the variables you are testing with double quotes!

Here's a list of useful options to `[` since I think you'd be interested:

```
-b file = True if the file exists and is block special file. 
-c file = True if the file exists and is character special file. 
-d file = True if the file exists and is a directory. 
-e file = True if the file exists. 
-f file = True if the file exists and is a regular file 
-g file = True if the file exists and the set-group-id bit is set. 
-k file = True if the files "sticky" bit is set. 
-L file = True if the file exists and is a symbolic link. 
-p file = True if the file exists and is a named pipe. 
-r file = True if the file exists and is readable. 
-s file = True if the file exists and its size is greater than zero. 
-s file = True if the file exists and is a socket. 
-t fd = True if the file descriptor is opened on a terminal. 
-u file = True if the file exists and its set-user-id bit is set. 
-w file = True if the file exists and is writable. 
-x file = True if the file exists and is executable. 
-O file = True if the file exists and is owned by the effective user id. 
-G file = True if the file exists and is owned by the effective group id. 
file1 –nt file2 = True if file1 is newer, by modification date, than file2. 
file1 ot file2 = True if file1 is older than file2. 
file1 ef file2 = True if file1 and file2 have the same device and inode numbers. 
-z string = True if the length of the string is 0. 
-n string = True if the length of the string is non-zero. 
string1 = string2 = True if the strings are equal. 
string1 != string2 = True if the strings are not equal. 
!expr = True if the expr evaluates to false. 
expr1 –a expr2 = True if both expr1 and expr2 are true. 
expr1 –o expr2 = True is either expr1 or expr2 is true.
```

Comment: yep :) in bash: "always quote variables when you are testing"

Comment: If you want to check that they are in fact numbers, maybe something like `case $x in '' | *[!0-9]* ) die in French ;; esac` and ditto for `$y`.

Comment: Thanks for the complement :) (die in French -> "mourir")
and it works, but if i just press ENTER without any value, it doesn't work. I tried to use -e to prevent that, but it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

The operator `-e` is not the right operator to use in this situation. The operator `-z` is the right operator. This checks to see if a string is empty; in your case `x` and `y`.

So change this:

```
if [ !-e $x ] || [ !-e $y ]
```

to this:

```
if [ ! -z $x ] || [ ! -z $y ]
```

The operator -e is used to check if a file exists.

Comment: Yeah it works, but if i just press ENTER without any value, it doesn't work. I tried to use -e to prevent that, but it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can use:

```
if [[ -z $x || -z $y ]]; then
```

`[[` has a number of features which make it easier to use than `test`/`[`, including the ability to put `||` and `&&` directly into the expression, and the fact that you don't need to quote parameter expansions because `[[` does it automatically.

```
help [[
```

will give you some more information, although it leaves out this useful paragraph, which you can find in `man bash`:

```
  Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the
  words between the [[ and ]]; tilde expansion, parameter and
  variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution,
  process substitution, and quote removal are performed. Conditional
  operators such as -f must be unquoted to be recognized as primaries.
```